# How to communicate with a WCF Service (wsHttpBinding) & a .NET 2.0 client

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, .net-2.0

I have an issue with a webservice provided by a partner (I can't modify this service).

I must consume a WS-* web service (wsHttpBinding) with a .NET 2.0 client. I have the following exception:

```
SOAP header Action was not understood.
```

I know that it's not possible to communicate with WS- with .NET 2.0. I see it's possible to use WSE to communicate with WS-.

I do that but I have always the same error :

> SOAP header Action was not understood

.

Is it possible to work around this problem to communicate with this service ?

Comment: If you have control of the service, then, as Pablo says below, just add an endpoint using `basicHttpBinding`. If you don't have control, then you should do everything you can to avoid using WSE - it's obsolete and unsupported. It would be a much better choice to simply add .NET 4.0 to the .NET 2.0 system (unless the system is running Windows Server 2000 or some other unsupported OS).

Comment: No, I have no control of the service :(

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the basicHttpBinding to get it working with a .NET 2.0 client. That binding already provides the compatibility required by older clients or other platforms. If you still decide to go with wsHttpBinding, you will have to use Microsoft WSE to create messages in the .NET 2.0 client that are compatible with the wsHttpBinding.

Answer (score -1):

Usually consuming WCF services with .NET 2.0 applications changes the interface, adding a Boolean out parameter (success indicator), changing the return type to an out parameter and return type to void for each method.